# how to change the html structure of a react component when giving a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a web page for manga/manhua and I am right now in the part where the extracted chapters come out and I have a button that when pressed generates an animation that turns the image of the manga and puts the biography of the manga but I don't know How to make the text appear when turning, any advice or how to do it correctly?
(I haven't been in react for a long time)
this is my code

```
import React,{useRef, useState} from "react";
import "./Updates.css"
import ManhuaBio from "./ManhuaBio";
const Update = (props)=>{

    let turnAround = useRef()
    const [manhuauInfo,setManhuaInfo] = useState(true);

    const infoManhua = ()=>{
        setManhuaInfo(false)
    }   

    

    return(
        <div className={manhuauInfo ? "chapter-item" : <ManhuaBio/>} ref={turnAround}>
            <img src={props.image} className="chapter-item-iamge" />
            <div className="chapter-item-tittle-button">
                <h3>{props.tittle}</h3>
                <button className="chapter-item-button" onClick={infoManhua}>?</button>
            </div>
            <div className="chapter-item-name-date">
                <p>{props.Nchapter}</p>
                <p>{props.date}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Update;
```

Comment: It's not a correct syntax. It looks like if you wanted to insert a tag inside an opening tag. Try moving the conditional statement in the correct place.

Comment: Konrad Linkowski, what do you mean? Could you give me an example so that I can understand you?

Comment: You are trying to pass component in class name `<div className={manhuauInfo ? "chapter-item" : <ManhuaBio/>} ref={turnAround}>` how do you expect this to work?